# Some installed packages not available during runtime of container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am facing some difficulties with the following Dockerfile: https://github.com/IdanAdar/test-docker/tree/master

When I run the image locally, with these steps:

1. `docker run --privileged --dns 9.0.128.50 --dns 9.0.130.50 -d -P --name slave alpine-agent:0.0.1`
2. `docker ps` and copy the port number
3. `ssh -p <port number> jenkins@localhost`
4. password: jenkinspass

I am able to run almost all tools installed, with the following issues:

1. `sonar-scanner` is not found
2. The `PATH` doesn't include any of the `PATH` modifications from the Dockerfile

When I run the image in Jenkins as an agent, almost all tools installed are working, with the following issues:

1. `sonar-scanner` gets `sonar-scanner: Permission denied`
2. `ibmcloud` is not found (but is available in `usr/local/ibmcloud`)
3. The `PATH` doesn't include any of the PATH modifications from the Dockerfile
4. `sh` blocks in Jenkins are failing, for commands such as:

```
array=(some text some text ...)
```

With:

```
syntax error: unexpected "("
```

I'm having a hard time understanding why these issues are happening and how to resolve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured `PATH` variable with `ENV` command for user, which is used for container run - that is probably `root` and not `jenkins`. Your `Dockerfile` contains:

```
COPY skel/ /home/jenkins
```

so use `.bashrc` in `skel/` to configure `PATH` for `jenkins` user (it will be `/home/jenkins/.bashrc` in the image).

`Permission denied` issue: check if binary has execute permissions for `jenkins` user.

`syntax error: unexpected "("` issue: `/bin/sh` in `docker:stable-dind` is `busybox` which doesn't understand this syntax (see `ls -l /bin/sh`). Install bash in Dockerfile (`apk add bash`) and "point" `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`. For example:

```
mv /bin/sh /bin/sh.bak
ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
```